# Is there any incompatibility between affine spaces and Hilbert spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, affine-geometry

I was wondering if there is such a vector space which is both a Hilbert and affine? I've seen the definition of an Euclidian affine space, which is:

An affine space (A, V, φ) is a Euclidean affine space if the vector space V is a Euclidean vector space.

Thus, it makes me think that an affine space would be a Hilbertian affine space if the vector space V is a Hilbertian vector space. Is this right? or is there any incompatibility between both spaces (affine and Hilbert spaces)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Hilbertian space"